# I found a Key error of 'start' when using pytube.caption

Tags: python, keyerror, pytube

I am trying to download Youtube captions by pytube.

Everything was fine and I managed to download the video and its caption by xml_captions.

However, when I tried to covert it into .srt format, I got a key error.

> ```
> ---> 83             start = float(child.attrib["start"])  
> KeyError: 'start'
> ```

I wonder what was wrong.
My code is

```
pip install pytube
from pytube import YouTube
# misc``
import os
import shutil
import math
import datetime
video=YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxydY73V9bQ')
caption = video.captions['a.en']
caption.xml_captions
srt_format = caption.xml_caption_to_srt(caption.xml_captions)
```

Comment: The error seems clear: there's no `start` key in the `child.attrib` dictionary.

Comment: that line isn't in the code you posted. You haven't shown how you set `child`.

Answer (score 1):

If sill relevant: tt appears that YouTube has changed the way captions are handled. [Here's a discussion](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1085) with possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remplace some code in

> caption.py

```
--- captions.py.orig    2023-04-01 03:12:55.176218471 +0200
+++ captions.py 2023-04-01 03:12:59.320187087 +0200
@@ -82,14 +82,14 @@
         segments = []
         root = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_captions)
-        for i, child in enumerate(list(root)):
+        for i, child in enumerate(list(root[0])):
             text = child.text or ""
             caption = unescape(text.replace("\n", " ").replace("  ", " "),)
             try:
-                duration = float(child.attrib["dur"])
+                duration = float(child.attrib["d"]) / 1000.0
             except KeyError:
                 duration = 0.0
-            start = float(child.attrib["start"])
+            start = float(child.attrib["t"]) / 1000.0
             end = start + duration
             sequence_number = i + 1  # convert from 0-indexed to 1.
             line = "{seq}\n{start} --> {end}\n{text}\n".format(
```

Not mine found it on https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1477